# Role of `Microsoft.Owin` in ASP.NET 4: No `app.run` required?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, owin, asp.net-4.0, asp.net-4.5

I try to get more understanding of the role of the Owin packages (`Microsoft.Owin`) in ASP.NET 4 (MVC 5) applications.

When I create a new MVC application with the wizard, it sets me up with an Owin `Startup` class, but the configuration therein deals only with authentication.

In contrast to ASP.NET 5, there seems to be no need to do a `app.RunMvc()` - or in fact any kind of `app.Run*()` or mentioning what comes at the end of the pipeline.

That begs the question of how the apparently existing Owin pipeline is brought into ASP.NET in ASP.NET 4 applications where the dependency on `System.Web` still exists.

I assume that

- in ASP.NET 4, the Owin pipeline always implicitly ends with standard ASP.NET routing (from `System.Web.Routing`) which, in MVC apps, is usually configured with `MapRoute` on the `RouteCollection` and comes down to an `MvcRouteHandler` and
- in ASP.NET 5, the Owin pipeline should be explicitly ended with an `app.Run*()` because nothing comes after its end by default.

Is that correct?

Comment: More or less. In ASP.NET 4 the OWIN pipeline executes inside a single HttpModule. If you reach the end of he OWIN pipeline it returns control to IIS and the next module runs, e.g. ASP.NET.

Comment: In ASP.NET 5 it's not actually an OWIN pipeline, but it looks pretty similar. When you reach the end of the pipeline there is a default component that returns 404. This is also how the OWIN pipeline behaves outside of IIS (e.g. using HttpListener).

Comment: Ah, the pipeline one builds in the ASP.NET 5 `Startup` thing isn't an Owin pipeline - I confused that because it looks so similar and I assumed the differences were due to versioning. But in both cases, there is a package `Microsoft.Owin` and `Microsoft.AspNet.Owin`, respectively, that introduces the Owin pipeline. It's just that in the case of ASP.NET 5 one has to explicitly say `app.UseOwin()` to install it whereas for ASP.NET 4 it's somehow there without it (I don't have a special Owin model installed in my web.config).

Comment: In Asp.Net 4 the OwinHttpModule is dynamically registered.

Comment: @Tratcher Oh, didn't know that was even possible. And in ASP.NET 5, there's no module and `app.UseOwin` merely adds something to the ASP.NET 5 middleware pipeline, I understood that now.